# Pythonic way of indexing 2d array with list of coordinates

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-image

I have coordinates of class `numpy.ndarray` and of dimensions `(200,2)`. Basically the output from [regionprops](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.regionprops).

I want to index a image matrix (also an `ndarray`) of dim `img.shape = (1000,1000)`. 
I want to be able to do something like

```
for prop in region:
    img[prop.coords] = 0
```

However, what happens is, it doesn't see the coordinates as row, column pairs. But rather, each number as a row number and sets that entire row to 0.

How can I fix this?

I tried reshaping the array but that doesn't seem to work either. The only other think I can think of is to convert those indices into a matrix, where the matrix is same size as image dimensions and those coordinates are 1 and all the other coordinate values are 0. Then, index using this matrix. However, this doesn't seem any more efficient than just brute forcing it using a for loop.

Comment: is `img` an `ndarray` too? Or is it a pillow image

Comment: img is ndarray too, i'll update the question

Comment: Are you looking for `img[prop.coords[:,0], prop.coords[:,1]] = 0`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to supply the coordinates as a tuple in order to invoke basic indexing:

```
for prop in region:
    img[tuple(prop.coords.T)] = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
for prop in region:
    (min_row, min_col, max_row, max_col) = prop['bboxtuple']
    img[min_row:max_row, min_col:max_col] = 0
```